# Facebook skd 3.0 login

Tags: android, facebook

I've integrated my app with facebook login. This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {


          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {


            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {
                TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                t.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }`
```

in device emulator this code works, but when i try it in my device the app get me this message:
so, when i click ok, the textView is not setted with the name of user. Why?

Comment: http://www.provablackout.altervista.org/img.jpg (message)

Comment: is your code placed inside Fragment or Activity?

Comment: oh, I had similar issue because onActivityResult() was never called in my Fragment. Otherwise your code seems fine. Put @Override before onActivityResult() and check if it is really called. If this won't help, I can give you a bit different example from my project that worked for me both on emulator and on device.

Comment: @user711058 Can you post your code pls?

Comment: I've put together an article which fully explains opening a Facebook session: [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/facebook-android-sdk-30-opening-session.html).

Answer (score 0):

I need extra permissions for reading, so my code looks like this:

```
    OpenRequest req = new OpenRequest(getActivity()).setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {                
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            //do login stuff
                        } else {
                            //show error message

                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                if (exception != null) {
                    //show error
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
    req.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_location"));
    Session session = new Builder(getActivity()).build();
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    session.openForRead(req);
```

This is inside Fragment, so you can replace `getActivity()` with `this`.
With correct onActivityResult() method I have no problems with FB.

Comment: when i replace getActivity() with this i have this error: `the method setcallback is undefined for the type MainActivity `

Comment: check your brackets. Should be: OpenRequest req = new OpenRequest(this).setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() { ...

Comment: The problem is not solved. In emulator works but not in my device. Do u have another solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You can check for Facebook replies, though. Put `if (response.getError() != null) Log.d("error!", response.getError().getErrorMessage());` inside call() callback and also log every session state change. If it is your test project, you can also place the full source code somewhere, I can check it later.